# Why does the order of function order matter?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am having a problem with a function I am trying to fit to some data. I have a model, given by the equation inside the function which I am using to find a value for v. However, the order in which I write the variables in the function definition greatly effects the value the fit gives for v. If, as in the code block below, I have `def MAR_fit(v,x)` where x is the independent variable, the fit gives a value for v hugely different from if I have the definition `def MAR_fit(x,v)`. I haven't had a huge amount of experience with the curve_fit function in the scipy package and the docs still left me wondering.

Any help would be great!

```
def MAR_fit(v,x):
    return (3.*((2.-1.)**2.)*0.05*v)/(2.*(2.-1.)*(60.415**2.)) * (((3.*x*((2.-1.)**2.)*v)/(60.415**2.))+1.)**(-((5./2.)-1.)/(2.-1.))

x = newCD10_AVB1_AMIN01['time_phys'][1:]


y = (newCD10_AVB1_AMIN01['MAR'][1:])
popt_tf, pcov = curve_fit(MAR_fit, x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html?highlight=curve_fit#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) again, it says that the callable that you pass to `curve_fit` (the function you are trying to fit) must take the independent variable as its first argument. Further arguments are the parameters you are trying to fit. You must use `MAR_fit(x,v)` because that is what `curve_fit` expects.

Comment: Yeah that is what I expected, it was the example on the documentation that prompted me to change it to (x,v) in the first place. It provides me with a much more sensible value for v, though the actual fit does not follow the data (the fit is a straight line, the data is more of a power law) Thankyou !